# Google apps domain wide apps script properties using GAS

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps, google-sheets-api, google-docs-api

I need a domain global variable that will be set by the apps administrator of a domain and all the users apps script will read the variable and apply the settings inside their apps script.

The script is deployed as a web app. However, script property or document property cannot be used since the apps script is can be deployed across many domains. aka for a domain it should be unique property.

For example, 
I am an apps admin of 'mydomain.edu', I set as

```
scriptProperties.setProperty('EXAMPLE_PROP', 'mydomain.edu_property');
```

Some other apps admin of 'somedomain.edu' sets

```
scriptProperties.setProperty('EXAMPLE_PROP', 'somedomain.edu_property');
```

Then, the setting will be in conflict. I need each domain to have unique value set to the property EXAMPLE_PROP for the same apps script.

Comment: You can add a domain Identifier to property key like so: "mydomain.edu_Example_Prop" for your domain. Likewise, "somedomain.edu_Example_Prop" for the other domain. And when the web app is accessed it will install settings based on domain of the user accessing it

Comment: But if the app is installed for more and more admins worldwide, it is likely that size of scriptProperties will overflow? What is the size of scriptProperties ?

Comment: Have you considered passing parameters as part of the web app URL?  If launched from an intranet page the admin would just change part of the link.

Comment: Why not just store everything you need in a file.  I prefer file storage over the PropertiesService.  And you'll never overflow the file nor will you get the errors that your arguments are too large. The administrator can share a readonly file with all users in a given domain.

Comment: It's true, but say admin has made a file having path/1.json now,  then the admin has to advertise each users about the path/1.json? How to fetch the path by the app without troubling the users. As the app is installed domain wide by admin

Comment: Don't all files that are shared with me show up in "shared with me"?  Isn't it enough that I can access them that way, without even knowing their path?

Comment: Exactly, thank you Cooper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was store everything in a file.  The administrator can share a readonly version of the file with all users in a given domain. I have a bunch of utilities I wrote for storing simple arrays and dictionaries in text files [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42866064/re-execute-all-matching-functions-in-a-spreadsheet/42868611#42868611).

Note: This may not be an acceptable answer see notes below.
[And this link](https://support.google.com/drive/forum/AAAAOxCWsTosAqFmdPPxYc/?hl=en)

Comment: But if a file is shared, it is not visible neither in shared with me folder nor via apps script. The read only version is only accessible once the user opens the link https://support.google.com/drive/forum/AAAAOxCWsTosAqFmdPPxYc/?hl=en

Comment: So you have to receive a link to click on before your can see that file in shared with me.  Can you access that file with Google Script After you click on the link.